# Many &nbsp in the DOM, but none in the source

Tags: html

I need some help here: http://www.otojo.com/ is the site. If you scroll down to the article titled '**Latest Cyanogen nightly adds FM radio to Nexus One**', you can see that the description went out of place in firefox. If you inspect it via Firefox addon, it shows a lot of &nbsp. But if you view its source, there's no &nbsp. Seems like firefox automatically added in the &nbsp, causing the layout to distort. I checked the source of the data, and there's no &nbsp in there either.

Problem only in Firefox, not IE. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: yup, that's weird.  At first I thought it might be related to the fancy double-quote marks, but other places that have those don't have nbsps.

Comment: Those definitely aren't spaces - doing a strict comparison between that whitespace char and a space returned false.

Answer (score 8):

There are Unicode non-breaking spaces in that page.

Running a hexdump of your page:

```
00009d00  a0 53 74 61 62 6c 65 c2  a0 73 68 6f 74 c2 a0 63  |.Stable..shot..c|
00009d10  61 6d 65 72 61 c2 a0 6d  6f 64 65 c2 a0 2d c2 a0  |amera..mode..-..|
```

Notice the `c2 a0` where you would expect a `20` (space) to be?  That's the Unicode [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) character in UTF-8, which is also representable as, you guessed it, `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, did you save the page and open in a hex editor? Or, is there some awesome tool I don't know about yet?  :)

Comment: @Steve, seconded.  I'd love it if there were a tool for this.

Comment: i don't know what tool Zoogie used, but many text editors have a hex view these days. I use the free [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/), which even adds an "Open as Hex" to the Explorer context menu. I know [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) also has a hex mode.

Comment: @Steve: I'm a Unix-y type of guy, so: `wget -O index.html 'http://www.otojo.com/'; hexdump -C index.html > dump.txt; vim dump.txt`  :)

Answer (score 1):

&nbsp; is character code 160. Possibly whatever you're using to make that page is actually inserting that code into your page in place of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Newline (by pressing ENTER) also causes this problem. check whether any new line there

**EDIT:**

The problem is hyphen(-) which makes the sentence as single line .

replace following in your p tag its fine

> In the latest “hack an FM radio onto
>   that Android device” news, Cyanogen
>   has added FM radio to the Nexus One.
>   In the latest changelog of the
>   Cyanogen nightly build, the notes
>   state that the changes
>   include:Common:Stableshotcameramode
>   CyanogenCommon:Dual-modesnooze(longpressdismiss)
>   EvanCharltonCommon:ComposeSMS/MMSviasearchbuttonlongpress
>   WesGarnerN1:FMRadiosupport
>   MIUI-http://miui.comN1/DS/Hero
>   Slightlyb

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's coming from your source. Go to the source page delete a few spaces and add them again. See if the problem goes away. If it does do it for the rest of the teaser.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, first of all, you should try to validate your html markup ([here](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.otojo.com%2F)) - there's lots of errors which can cause firefox to behave seriously curious. I think searching for this specific error only makes sense when those "easy-to-fix"-errors are gone.